# FactoryBot and Devise Users can't login during tests with ajax form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, capybara, factory-bot

I did an override of the default `devise/sessions/new.html.erb` to make use of AJAX requests with the `remote: true` option:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), remote: true, disable_with: '...') do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control', autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control', autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group text-center">
    <%= f.submit "Log in", class: 'btn btn-default btn-auth' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I have FactoryBot setup to do the follwing:

```
factory :user do
   sequence(:email) { |n| "tester_#{n}@example.com" }
   sequence(:name) { |n| "tester_#{n}" }
   password { "pass123" }
   password_confirmation { "pass123" }
   confirmed_at { Time.now }
end
```

Now the problem is when using RSpec and Capybara (poltergeist driver) I get the following from logs:

```
Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"email"=>"tester_1@ploywithme.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
[1m[36mUser Load (2.8ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["email", "tester_1@ploywithme.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 30ms (ActiveRecord: 9.6ms)
```

My spec looks like this:

```
user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
visit new_user_session_path
fill_in "user_email", with: user.email
fill_in "user_password", with: 'pass123'
click_button "Log in"
expect(page).to have_content("New object") # A button that should be visible after login
```

The weird thing is that if I have a server running on RAILS_ENV=development and I open a console and execute `user = FactoryBot.create(:user)`, now I have this user created by FactoryBot and I can log in with it (the `confirmed_at { Time.now }` makes sure the user is already confirmed)

*Any ideas why this could be happening?*

**EDIT:**

Project is running:

- rails 5.2.1
- rspec-rails 3.7.2
- capybara 2.18.0
- poltergeist 1.18.1
- database_cleaner 1.7.0

Inside the `spec_helper.rb` I initialize the dependencies like this:

```
# FactoryBot + Capybara + Poltergeist setup
config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
config.include Capybara::DSL

Capybara.server_port = 31337
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.register_driver(:poltergeist) do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new app, js_errors: false, timeout: 180
end

#Hooks
config.before(:all) do
  Capybara.reset_session!
end

config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
end

config.around(:each) do |example|
  DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
    example.run
  end
end
```

Devise is using the default `config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = true`

After some follow up questions I exclusively ran the `:feature` test that's failing to avoid other user sessions to intrude (by doing `bundle exec rspec spec/features/user_login_spec.rb`).

I also printed the number of users in the DB before and after the `user = FactoryBot.create(:user)`. **I can confirm there's only one user in the DB after the FactoryBot create the one used in the spec and no other Capybara sessions have interacted with the test server.**

Comment: What version or RoR? Is this the first test using Poltergeist that logs a user in you've added to your test suite?

Comment: Do you have `config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false` and `config.navigational_formats = ["*/*", :html, :json]` in `devise.rb`?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I'm using 5.2.1 and more details were added after an edit to the question

Comment: @Rigo the default `config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = true` is used and I don't see why I would have to change the `navigational_formats` option since everything works fine when developing locally and the access returns 401 during the tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of potential issues but it's most likely that your tests and test app  aren't seeing the same records in the DB.  The fix for this in Rails < 5.1 was to setup `database_cleaner` with a truncation/deletion strategy when running JS tests.  That changed with Rails 5.1+ where a DB connection can now be safely shared between tests and the app under test. This means database cleaner is no longer necessary. Since you're using Rails 5.2 remove all references to database cleaner from your configs and ensure you have `config.use_transactional_tests = true` (or `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true' depending on versions) in your RSpec config.

Another issue you may run into is `poltergeist` not being able to run modern JS, although since the JS submission is actually happening it's probably not the issue here. You still may want to consider swapping to using the selenium driver with headless Chrome or Firefox rather than poltergeist since you'll have a lot less issues (as well as easily being able to turn off headless to see what's actually happening when you have issues)

On a side note, you really shouldn't need to do `config.include Capybara::DSL` which will include Capybara::DSL into all your tests. When you require `capybara/rspec` Capybara sets up RSpec to include Capybara::DSL into the test types it's supported in (feature specs, and matchers in view specs).

Comment: The first suggestion doesn't really work for me since I get: `undefined method use_transactional_tests=' for #<RSpec::Core::Configuration`. If I get rid of `database_cleaner` the users created from the previous test run are there and conflict with the FactoryBot sequence resulting in `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email has already been take`. I guess there is a chance poltergeist can't work with this, although it's a little difficult to believe because it's supposed to be plain jquery-rails doing the AJAX. Anyways I guess I'll take a look into the selenium-headless driver

Comment: @Fdo It may be `use_transactional_fixtures = true` depending on rspec/rspec-rails version

Comment: Well, giving it a second thought there's a good chance the poltergeist driver works fine. In the logs I can see how the requests are being sent, they just fail once hitting the server with a `401 Unauthorized`

Comment: @Fdo - which is why I said `poltergeist` probably isn't the issue here :)

Comment: True, sorry missed that part :) By the way neither `use_transactional_fixtures`/`use_transactional_tests` work in the RSpec config. Aren't they part of the spec class instead? Check this out: https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/05/26/rails-5-renamed-transactional-fixtures-to-transactional-tests.html

Comment: Okay it ended up being an awful mistake in the **other** configuration file. It appeared as if `use_transactional_fixtures` (for rspec-rails 3.7) wasn't a config option because I was fiddling with `spec_helper.rb`. The default rspec installation created two files and the option is set as false in `rails_helper.rb`. So after setting as `true` in the latter file as a config option everything works as expected (transactions). Thanks for helping me debug this through